# How to programmatically add a UILabel to UICollectionViewCell in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, uicollectionview, xcode8, uicollectionviewcell

I have a few UICollectionViewCells and I want to add two labels to the cells programmatically. How would I do this the correct way?

Comment: add it from cellforrowatindexpath

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your cell class define it global.

```
class YourCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

        var titleLabel:UILabel = {
            let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x:100, y: 30, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width , height: 40))
            label.textAlignment = .left
            label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
            label.numberOfLines = 0
            return label
        }()

        override init(frame: CGRect) {
            super.init(frame: frame)
            self.addSubview(self.titleLabel)
        }
}
```

Comment: I am trying to add the labels to the UICollectionViewCells not the view

Comment: this is UICollectionViewCells already, I will share all the code , it will make sense

Answer (score -2):

You can google with keyword: `customize table view cell`

This is how you can do it:

Firstly, You need to create a subclass of `UICollectionViewCell` like so:

// I'll use `YourCellClass` as your `custom cell's class`

```
class YourCellClass: UITableViewCell {
// Your can add your label to this Cell
// Review @Özgür Ersil's code above
}
```

Then, you have to register this class to your table view. This class must have a Identifier

```
tableView.register(YourCellClass.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cellId")
```

then set `datasource` of your table view. And in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` add following code to get instance of your cell Class and return it for your table view row

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellId") as! YourCellClass
return cell
```

Comment: This is to create UITableViewCell, not adding UILabel to UICollectionViewCell.